# What is MAAS hard disk requirement(s) for Openstack deployment? RAID or JBOD?

Tags: partitioning, raid, maas, openstack

Am following [openstack wallaby charm deployment guide](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/wallaby/install-maas.html) and am stuck on the physical hard disk requirements. From the documentation it says:

```
4 x cloud nodes: 8GiB RAM, 2 CPUs, 2 NICs, 3 x 80GiB storage
```

In my case my 4 cloud nodes each have 8 physical disks of 1.8TB in raid 10 (PERC H730P Adp) which gives me 1 hard disk in each node of 7.2TB. Now my first question: Is it okay to go ahead and install openstack with this raid 10 settings, or should configure raid 0, or do away with raid(JBOD)? Which is best?

I have also read from [charmbase here](https://charmhub.io/openstack-base):

> The first disk is used for the node's operating system, and the second is for Ceph storage.

My second question is should i divide the disk in raid 10 into two and of what proportion/size or remove raid and provide physical disks (JBOD)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after alot of reading, the openstack wallaby (the version am deploying, with juju on MAAS Cluster), first hard drive is used to run the os, and openstack application and containers i.e. lxd. Therefore, i did not use the first hard drive for cloud storage in my case. Fortunately my server had 8 physical hard disk. I configured them as follow:

1. sda = 4 physical hard disks on raid 10, for os and apps
2. sdb = 1 physical hard disk on raid 0
3. sdc = 1 physical hard disk on raid 0
4. sdd = 1 physical hard disk on raid 0
5. The last hard disk was reserved for hot plug swap spare
   These were my settings for ceph osd:

```
ceph-osd:
  osd-devices: /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
  source: cloud:focal-wallaby
```

Further investigation suggest that you can add virtual disks (vdb) and you can also create folders in your first hard drive and reference to them as storage spaces. I did not implement this so am not sure.

Lastly, i would recommend [watching this video: Deploying a HA Openstack HomeLab with MaaS and the Juju CLI](https://youtu.be/QDRnjGtxQos), it explains briefly the whole deployment. I love [Sean Shuping youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/seanshuping). If you find the video resourceful like me, please like and subscribe. He makes cool content on MAAS, Juju and OpenStack.